# Cleaning inconsistent data categories in Python

Tags: python, data-science, data-cleaning

I have a Dataframe in Python which has a column for university degree types where the degrees are mentioned in a very inconsistent manner. In total there are about 12,654 unique degree types which will take a very long time to categorize manually.

For example, a Bachelors degree could be mentioned as any of the types below:

'Sc.B','S.B.','Dual Degree','BEng.','Bachelor of Law',
'B.sc','Bachelor of Applied Science (B.A.Sc.)',
'Bachelor of Engineering (BE)','Bs',
'Bachelor Engineering','(B.S.)',
"Bachelor's degree in business administration",
'Licenciatura',"Bachelor's of Science",
'B.Bus','Bachelor of Arts - BA',
'Bachelor of Science in Business Administration',
'BSCS','BSc(Hons)','B.S.E.E.','B Eng','B.Comm.',
'BSM',"Bachelor's degree in science with honors",
'Bachlor','Bachelor of business administration',
'B.Acc',"Bachelor's degree in arts with honors",
'B.S.E.E','L.L.B.','Liberal Arts','BsC','Bachelor"s Degree'

A Masters degree could be any of the types below:

'Master of Science ','M.S','MD',
"Master's",'M.A.','M.Eng','LLM','MFA','Masters of Science',
'PGDM','Executive Education','Graduation',
'LL.M','MPH','CA','Diplom','Executive Program',
'SM','L.L.M','Fellowship','Master of science',
'Master of Laws','Master of Science (M.S.)',
'Master of Science (MS)','Master degree',
'MsC','CFA','Graduate Diploma','M. Sc.',
'MTech','Master of Arts (M.A.)','CPA',
'Master of Business Administration - MBA',
'M.Ed','M.E.','Specialization','Master in Management ',
'AMP','Chartered Accountant','Residency',
'MED','MM','Masters of Arts','MASc',
'PGDBM','MPS','International MBA','(MBA)',
'M.Arch','MIS','MHA',"Master's degree in arts ",
'MSci','PG','M.Tech.','Master of Science - MS',
'master','M.Phil.','Masters degree'

and so on with high school, Associate and PHD.

I would like to find a short cut to classify most of them into either High School, Associate, Bachelor, Master or PHD/Doctorate level.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Some articles online have suggested using tools like Fuzzywuzzy. I have never used this and not sure if it would actually help me here.

I am really new to Python / Datascience and am not really sure how to go about this so please explain as clearly as possible.

Thank you and looking forward to a solution :)

Comment: Is your data in a python list? Or are you using a package like numpy or pandas? If it's just a list, a start would be to loop through the list, with an if/elif block, like `if 'bachelor' in degree_name: do_something() elif 'master' in degree_name: do_something_else()`, and so on,  and then see what's left, and write some more `elif`s for your edge cases.

Comment: @aidanS the dataset is basically a column from a data frame. Could you please explain further what you mean by the looping if and elif function?

Answer (score 0):

following on from my comment on your question:

this first block gets me a dataframe similar to what I imagine yours looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

your_list = np.array(['Sc.B','S.B.','Dual Degree','BEng. 2master','M.Phil.','Masters degree'])
names = np.array([f"person_{ii}" for ii in range(len(your_list))])

df = pd.DataFrame({"names": names, "degree_title": your_list})
print(df)
```

Now we can do a `for` loop over the degree_title data, with our first guess as
to what the degree classes might look like.

```
new_classifications = [] # Make an empty list so we can keep track of what we classify the new degree as.

for degree in df["degree_title"]:
    if "bachelor" in degree.lower(): # lower() as we don't care if it's "Bachelor" or "bachelor"
        new_classifications.append("bachelor") # Anything here is good enough to be called "bachelor"
    elif "master" in degree.lower():
        new_classifications.append("master")
    elif "doctorate" in degree.lower():
        new_classification.append("phd")
    else:
        new_classifications.append("unclassified")
        print(f"no classification found for {degree}")
```

This tells us that we're missing loads of results like B.Sc, so we can add checks for those in for our second attempt - note the additions to the "bachelor" and "master" lines.

Note that there's a line which gets "edge cases" - there's no way from the title that I'd be able to guess that "Specialisation" was a master's level qualification, so we have to do this on "manually".

```
new_classifications = [] 

for degree in df["degree_title"]:
    if "bachelor" in degree.lower() or degree.lower().startswith("b") or "b." in degree.lower():
        new_classifications.append("bachelor")
    elif "B" in degree and degree.isupper(): # Also require the whole title to be uppercase 
        new_classifications.append("bachelor")
    elif "master" in degree.lower() or degree.lower().startswith("m") or "m." in degree.lower():
        new_classifications.append("master")
    elif "M" in degree and degree.isupper():
        new_classifications.append("master")
    elif "doctorate" in degree.lower():
        new_classification.append("phd")
    elif degree in ["Diplom", "Fellowship", "CPA", "Specialisation", "Graduate Diploma"]:
        new_classifications.append("some_classification_that_you_write_for_these_edge_cases")
    else:
        new_classifications.append("unclassified")
        print(f"no classification found for {degree}")
```

When we're happy, we can add the nicely classified degrees to the dataframe

```
df["new_classification"] = new_classifications
print(df)
```

This is a very "brute force" way to approach this problem, but given that many degree titles will follow a similar pattern, it's quite an easy way to get started, and remove a bulk of the work leaving far fewer to classify by hand.

Comment: I highly doubt this is the way to go! If we are listing all of the possibilities and checking back and forth what's missing, then why not just replace them as well. It kinda looses the point of code. Kindly elaborate if I am missing anything

Comment: True - the three separate blocks were meant to be my "iterations" over the problem - improving each as I went, rather than all three blocks included in the actual code. I included them to show my thought process. However, if you think my answer is unhelpful, I can remove it.

Comment: Instead of removing, it would be better if you add more context to it like why it is useful in this scenario and why one should for opt for it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - I'm new to answering on StackOverflow, so it's good to get feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions. I will look into this and follow up accordingly. It seems like there is no easy way to clean up such data.